# shell rename file names with non-printable characters

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression, rename

I'm trying to find a way to batch rename file names which originally contains Japanese characters, which are non-printable in my shell.There is clearly something I'm missing here in understanding how regex works, in this use case,

When I run `ls` I have this :

```
AIR?t?H?[????002.jpg
AIR?t?H?[????009.jpg
AIR?t?H?[????075.jpg
```

And `ls -ldb *` give me this:

```
AIR\342t\342H\374[\342\353\342\307002.jpg
AIR\342t\342H\374[\342\353\342\307009.jpg
AIR\342t\342H\374[\342\353\342\307075.jpg
```

Basically I want to match and replace everything between **AIR** and **[0-9]***

I'm currently looking at something like that :

```
find AIR*.jpg -type f -exec sed -ri 's/(?<=AIR)(.*?)([0-9]*)/\2test/' {} +
```

But i get this error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 31: Invalid preceding regular expression

I have also tried using

```
echo AIR�t�H�\[����002.jpg | sed -r 's/AIR([^[:print:]\t\r])*/\1toto/g'
```

But it rename **AIR** instead of the "special character" group

> toto�t�H�[����002.jpg

And

```
echo AIR�t�H�\[����002.jpg | sed -r 's/AIR([^[:print:]\t\r])*/\2toto/g'
```

returns

> sed: -e expression #1, char 33: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS

Also `tr` seems it could be an option but I don't have only special characters within my two groups **AIR** and **[0-9]*** so here is what I got:

```
echo AIR�t�H�\[����002.jpg | tr -c '[:print:]\t\r\n'test '[ *]'
```

returns:

> AIR t H [    002.jpg

Comment: The `(?<=AIR)` syntax is not supported in `sed -r`. See [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` substitution looks for instances (all instances since you’re using `g`) matching the first argument, and replaces the full match with the second argument. So if you include “AIR” in the first argument, it will be replaced — you need to include it in the second argument if you want to keep it. When `sed` complains of an invalid reference, it means you haven’t defined a corresponding group in the first argument (using `\(` and `\)`, or `(` and `)` since you’ve specified `-r`).

Since you’re looking for “AIR” followed by any characters followed by digits, I would suggest the following:

```
sed -r 's/AIR([^[:digit:]]*)([[:digit:]]+).jpg/AIRtest\2.jpg/g'
```

This replaces “AIR” with “AIR”, any non-digits with “test”, and keeps all the digits thereafter. If you don’t need to process the characters between “AIR” and the digits, you can ignore them:

```
sed -r 's/AIR[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]+).jpg/AIRtest\1.jpg/g'
```

If you have the Perl `rename`, you can transpose this to rename your files:

```
rename 's/AIR[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]+).jpg/AIRtest\1.jpg/g' AIR*.jpg
```

or

```
rename 's/AIR[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]+).jpg/AIRtest$1.jpg/g' AIR*.jpg
```

(`rename` prefers `$` for group references).

Comment: The OP is using `sed -r` so the group matches are `(..)` rather than `\(..\)`

Comment: Super thanks a lot ! it work using `rename` instead of `sed` which was opening all the files one by one instead of renaming the files title..
will have more `sed` documentation reading to avoid that ^^